# Function Which Takes Only A Finite Number Of Values

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Does there exist a function $f(x)$ such that it takes only a finite number of values for all $x$ in $[a, b]$ and is Riemann Integrable on $[a, b]$ and is not piecewise constant. If yes please give an example and if no then how to prove this??

Comment: But $\sqrt{x}$ takes infinitely many values on $[1, 2]$

Comment: Your latex code is incorrect, i am unable to understand

Comment: But how to proceed further??

Comment: But if we consider the function $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational takes only two values but is not piece wise constant

Comment: I think you may want to use the term "locally constant" instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[a, b] = [0, 1]$ and $C$ be the cantor set. Define $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ as $$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in C \\ 0 & x \notin C\end{cases}$$

It is continuous at all points not in $C$ since it is locally constant there. ($C$ is closed and thus, its complement is open. Thus, given any $x \notin C$, we can find an interval around $x$ contained in the complement of $C$.)

Thus, $f$ is Riemann integrable. (Its set of discontinuities has measure zero.)

On the other hand, $f$ is not "piecewise-constant" (I assume you meant "locally constant") since it is not locally constant at any $x \in C$.

Clearly, $f$ does take only finitely many values.